# Host Named Site Collection show IIS8 default home page

Tags: 2013, site-collection, host-named

I created web application using Powershell then created Root Site Collection via CA after that created a Host Named Site collection using Powershell. following is the script. but when I browse to the sc it shows the default iis home page (localhost).

```
$ap = New-SPAuthenticationProvider
$wa = New-SPWebApplication -DatabaseName $dataBaseName –ApplicationPool $appPool -ApplicationPoolAccount $appPoolAccount -Name $name -Url $url -Port 80 -HostHeader $hostHeader -AuthenticationProvider $ap



New-SPSite "http://company.Intranet.com" -OwnerAlias "Dev\Amdinistrator" -HostHeaderWebApplication $wa -Name "Company" –Template "BLANKINTERNET#0" -ContentDatabase $dbName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating web applications when targeting Host Named Site Collections SHOULD NOT have a HOST HEADER (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx).

From the script it seems you've considered the ***-HostHeader $hostHeader*** parameter

Comment: thank you, I have now removed hostheader parameter and created a new web application and created an empty site in CA to the web application root but still it goes to same as localhost also the default iis8 page.

Comment: the only way to create an new site in the HNSC is Powershell, in the link provided the actual script is provided. Also, please validate you do not have another IIS Web running on port 80 (e.g. default web site)!

Comment: so, when You create a HNSC you have to have only one web application runing on port 80? it is why I get this error. thanks

Comment: if you have another web application running on the port 80, it will for sure conflict with sharepoint's one.